# Move a WPF Shape

Tags: wpf, move, shapes

I cannot figure out how to move a WPF shape at runtime.  Specifically, I want to move a ellipse.

Here is my current code:

```
private void Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point ballLocation = ball.TransformToAncestor(Application.Current.MainWindow).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
        //MessageBox.Show(ballLocation.ToString());
        Canvas.SetLeft(ball, ballLocation.X + 5);

        InvalidateVisual();
    }
```

Every time the timer ticks (1 second) the ball should move 5 pixels in the x direction, correct?  If this is wrong, how do I get the current location of the Ellipse and how do I set it to a new location.  Maybe there is a problem with the InvalidateVisual?  I believe that basically repaints the control.  If that is wrong, how do I repaint the ellipse to show its change in location. I am also tried ball.InvalidateVisual(), it did not work.

This is how I create and start the timer:

```
var timer = new DispatcherTimer {IsEnabled = true};
        timer.Tick += Tick;
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        timer.Start();
```

Comment: I have tried that, it did not work.

Comment: How do you create and start the timer?

Comment: I added that code to the post

Comment: The `IsEnabled = true` and `timer.Start()` calls are redundant, both are starting the timer. Otherwise it looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

If `Canvas.Left` is initialized with some value, either in XAML

```
<Ellipse Name="ball" Canvas.Left="0" ... />
```

or in code

```
Canvas.SetLeft(ball, 0);
```

the following works:

```
void Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Canvas.SetLeft(ball, Canvas.GetLeft(ball) + 5);
}
```

The initialization is necessary because the default value is `Double.NaN`.

---

You may however consider to animate the `Canvas.Left` property to get a smooth movement. Start reading here: [Animation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx)

Comment: This approach did not work.  I must be doing something wrong in my code elsewhere.

Comment: You might also post the XAML where you declare the Ellipse.